# Two completely different norms on a unital algebra!

Tags: banach-algebras

Does there exist any unital normed algebra $(A,\|\cdot\|)$ enjoying another  norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ such that

1. $(A,\|\cdot\|_1)$  forms a unital normed algebra with the same unit.
2. Any element contained in the intersection
   $$
   \{x\in A : \|x-1\|<1\}\bigcap \{x\in A : \|x-1\|_1<1\}
   $$ is in the form of $\alpha.1$  where $\alpha$ is a complex number  with $0<|\alpha|\leq
   1$?

Comment: For any non-scalar element $x$, let $a > {\rm min}(\|x\|, \|x\|_1)$. Then $1 + \frac{1}{a}x$ belongs to both sets.

Comment: Your delightful "enjoying another norm" has made my day

Comment: @DenisSerre I usually write the scalar before the vector, not sure what your convention is.

Comment: @NiK Your argument is really nice and makes one more point which I arrange it as another question.

Comment: @AliBagheri I don't understand how your edit changes the problem (or what it has to do with my counterexample).

Comment: @Nik Your answer is completely right. Based on the point mentioned by Meisam Soleimani (below) I made some changes to remove trivial cases.

Answer (score 1):

No, because 1 is in the intersection mentioned in hypothesis (2), but $1\neq\alpha1$ for any $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|<1$.

Comment: Thanks Meisam, I made some changes to remove trivial cases.

Comment: @AliBagheri, your changes do not remove triviality, because by Nik's comment your hypothesis imply that the algebra to be trivial.